# How to keep Visual Studio's add-ins enabled despite Shift key is held at startup?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, add-in, startup

When starting Visual Studio 2008 in Windows 7 with <kbd>Shift</kbd> key pressed, it disables all add-ins.

However this is a common scenario when starting a second instance of the VS from pinned taskbar icon (Shift-click on the icon). Is there a way to disable this behavior or to remap it to another key?

Middle-click is not an option to me as my mouse's wheel is very inconvenient for clicking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite simple: instead of shift-clicking the taskbar icon, right click it and select *Microsoft Visual Studio 2008* from the jump list that appears. You can start as many instances as you like this way (one at a time of course).